# Hadoop Pig - Optimizing Word Count

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, apache-pig

In the canonical pig wordcount example, I'm curious how folks approach optimizing the condition where grouping by word could result in a bag with many (many) elements.

For example:

```
A = load 'input.txt';
B = foreach A generate flatten(TOKENIZE((chararray)$0)) as word;
C = group B by word;
D = foreach C generate COUNT(B), group;
```

In line C, if there is a word, let's say "the", that occurs 1 billion times in the input file, this can result in the reducer hanging for a very long time while processing. What can be done to optimize this?

Answer (score 0):

In any case, PIG will assess if a combiner can be used and will have one if so.

In the case of your example, it will obviously introduce a combiner which will reduce the number of key value pairs per word to a few or only one in best case. So on the reducer side you will not end up with huge number of key/ values per a given word.

Comment: You're correct that recent versions of Pig will automatically combine these which you will see in the explain statements. While this will reduce the # of key value pairs that go into the reducers for high-occurrence words, in practice, it doesn't appear to be reducing it that much. These hot spots can cause a single reducer to get stuck for hours after everything else has finished. Any other optimizations?